# What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?

Tags: php, string, syntax

I'm a little confused why I see some code in PHP with string placed in single quotes and sometimes in double quotes.

I just know in .NET, or the C language, if it is in a single quote, that means it is a character, not a string.

Answer (score 1235, accepted):

[**PHP strings**](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) can be specified not just in *two* ways, but in **four** ways.

1. [**Single quoted strings**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) will display things almost completely "as is." Variables and most escape sequences will not be interpreted. The exception is that to display a literal single quote, you can escape it with a back slash `\'`, and to display a back slash, you can escape it with another backslash `\\` (**So yes, even single quoted strings are parsed**).
2. [**Double quote strings**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) will display a host of escape sequences (including some regexes), and variables in the strings will be evaluated. An important point here is that **you can use curly braces to isolate the name of the variable you want evaluated**. For example let's say you have the variable `$type` and you want to `echo "The $types are"`. That will look for the variable `$types`. To get around this use `echo "The {$type}s are"`. Take a look at [string parsing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) to see how to use array variables and such.
3. [**Heredoc**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) string syntax works like double quoted strings. It starts with `<<<`. After this operator, an identifier is provided, then a newline. The string itself follows, and then the same identifier again to close the quotation. You don't need to escape quotes in this syntax.
4. [**Nowdoc**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) (since PHP 5.3.0) string syntax works essentially like single quoted strings. The difference is that not even single quotes or backslashes have to be escaped. A nowdoc is identified with the same `<<<` sequence used for heredocs, but the identifier which follows is enclosed in single quotes, e.g. `<<<'EOT'`. **No parsing is done in nowdoc.**

**Notes:**
Single quotes inside of single quotes and double quotes inside of double quotes must be escaped:

```
$string = 'He said "What\'s up?"';
$string = "He said \"What's up?\"";
```

**Speed:**
There is *no difference*.
Please read a [credible article](https://www.npopov.com/2012/01/09/Disproving-the-Single-Quotes-Performance-Myth.html) on the matter from one of PHP core developers. Speaking of tests, one should never take them for granted. It must be understood that writing a credible test and, especially, interpreting its results requires a lot of knowledge and experience. Which means that most tests out there are just bogus. For example, in a code like this

```
for($i=0;$i<100000;$i++) {
    'string';
}
```

The quoted string gets parsed only *once*, along with entire script, and then gets translated into opcode. Which is then gets executed a million times. So it measures anything but parsing. And that's only a tip of the iceberg. For a nanobenchmark like this, it's practically impossible to create a credible test that wouldn't be spoiled by some interfering side effect.

Comment: +1 for the curly brace trick. Wasn't aware of that. Too bad it doesn't follow the same conventions as shell scripts, i.e. `${variablename}`.

Comment: I only use double quotes, when i need it for `\n`, anything else in my `PHP` code is in single quotes.

Comment: seems 'heredoc' is ported to PHP from bash or is it not? Anyways great answer, so a +1 Thanks.

Comment: @sjsam - looks like it - neat, didn't know that: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Comment: Interesting note in PHP documentation comments: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#120160 - "The double-quoted strings "which look so $slow since they have to parse everything for \n backslashes and $dollar signs to do variable expansion", turned out to be the FASTEST string concatenation method in PHP - PERIOD! Single-quotes are only faster if your string is completely literal (with nothing to parse in it and nothing to concatenate), but the margin is very tiny and doesn't matter."

Comment: Note: slowness of `"` double quotes is all but a thing of the past.  Updates have increased processing of double quotes to be as fast, in all but extreme cases, these days.

Comment: +1 for the curly brace trick. Wasn't aware of that. Too bad it doesn't follow the same conventions as shell scripts, i.e. ${variablename}. I too agree with this. Just now got to know.

Comment: I write double quotes when it is needed. That way when I see a string starting with double quotes it's because we use features not possible with single quotes. I wish they did allow all esapes in single quotes except variable interpolation since that would have been perfect, but breaking change.

Comment: Would it make sense to follow the shell script convention? I think the $ sign is like an operator itself in php, which means "evaluate this variable as an expression". That's why instance variables are set by $this->name = "John", not this $this->$name = "John", because that would mean set something like $this->"Jimmy"="John" vs $this[0x0001] = "John". I think without the dollar sign the compiler converts the variable to its pointer

Comment: @devios1 @aviboy2006 both `${variablename}` and `{$variablename}` in double quotes work!

Comment: @SherylHohman that's actually a horrible note, for its conclusions and - expecially - for its bogus "performance rules". Use whatever quotes you like as it makes absolutely no difference is the only acceptable conclusion.

Answer (score 250):

Things get evaluated in double quotes but not in single:

```
$s = "dollars";
echo 'This costs a lot of $s.'; // This costs a lot of $s.
echo "This costs a lot of $s."; // This costs a lot of dollars.
```

Comment: Escaped single quotes and escaped backslashes are expanded even in single quoted strings.

Comment: A mistake that many developers new to PHP are running in:

`$mailbody = 'I want a line break:\nDone.';` is keeping the `\n` alive. Whereas: `$mailbody = "I want a line break:\nDone.";` will parse the line break.

Comment: My two cents is needed only for interviews or for malware development. 

Just compare var_dump() from two expressions:

`$testWithAsciiAndUtf8Characters = "\x48\x41\x4c\114\117 \u{0147}\u{012B}\u{0144}\u{014D}!";`

`$simpleTest = '\x48\x41\x4c\114\117 \u{0147}\u{012B}\u{0144}\u{014D}!';`

Character sequences in `$testWithAsciiAndUtf8Characters` were transformed to string with real letters.

Answer (score 75):

## `'` Single quoted

The simplest way to specify a string is to enclose it in single quotes. Everything inside single quotes is treated as a plain string.

**Example:**

```
echo 'Start with a simple string';
echo 'Variables $var and escape sequences \n do not get interpolated';
echo 'You only need to escape the quote \' and a backslash itself\\';
```

---

## `"` Double quoted

Strings in double quotes interpolate variables and a wide range of escape sequences. Note: Use curly braces `{}` to include complex variables or in case when next character after a variable is a valid character for a variable name.

**Example:**

```
echo "Start with a simple string";
echo "String's apostrophe";
echo "Escape sequences get interpolated\n";
echo "Variables $var get interpolated as well {$name}_sake";
```

---

### Is there a performance benefit single quote vs double quote in PHP?

No.

In order to improve performance, PHP parses the entire code once and then stores the resulting bytecode in the [opcode cache](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php). This approach eliminates the entire parsing, along with whatever quoited strings as well.

Comment: The *one* exception to single quotes NOT parsing anything within the string, is what you can use `\'` to escape a single apostrophe for use within the string (or `\\'` to display the backslash).  Note that traditional escape sequences, such as `\n` will NOT get parsed to the newline character. [PHP docs on strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: I see on all of the answers that: you can use the variable's name inside a double quote to print out the variable's value, but you're saying, the variable name should also be enclosed within curly braces to avoid the need for using a concatenating period. So if both "$my_var" and "{$my_var}" output $my_var's value, what are the braces for? Thanks!

Comment: @Bahman.A I know it's been years and you probably already know the answer by this point but in case others are looking in future for the same thing: The curly branches are added when vars are used in double quotes primarily for readability of the code. Highly useful when quickly scanning to grok it is a var and not a string literal.

Comment: @Bahman.A I believe that the reason why you would use `"{$one}"` instead of `"$one"` isn't readability but instead for exact variable lookup. `{ }` also allows for array and object lookups. The dot operator, used for concatination of strings, would still be required for a function lookup

Comment: It also allows you to write `{$foo}bar`, as `$foobar` would get interpreted as `{$foobar}`.

Answer (score 44):

A single-quoted string does not have variables within it interpreted.  A double-quoted string does.

Also, a double-quoted string can contain apostrophes without backslashes, while a single-quoted string can contain unescaped quotation marks.

Comment: Single quoted strings also use less memory.  The fastest way to handle strings in PHP is with single quotes and using the . operator to concatenate strings and variables.

Comment: hmmm, correct me if I'm wrong but the base language for PHP is C right? Then why string quotes differ in PHP and C?

Comment: @rob waminal: PHP may be implemented in C, but it is a different language.  The PHP language specifies these semantics.

Comment: @Ribald - Wouldn't nowdoc syntax be faster? Single quoted strings are parsed for escaped single quotes and backslashes.

Comment: @Peter, you may be correct,  I've never bothered to really dig in to it. The PHP documentation makes the speed claim, I decided to believe the docs on faith. :)

Comment: @RibaldEddie now that's something new. Got any proof?

Answer (score 37):

In PHP, both `'my name'` and `"my name"` are string. You can read more about it [at the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php).

Thing you should know are

```
$a = 'name';
$b = "my $a"; == 'my name'
$c = 'my $a'; != 'my name'
```

In PHP, people use single quote to define a constant string, like `'a'`, `'my name'`, `'abc xyz'`, while using double quote to define a string contain identifier like `"a $b $c $d"`.

Answer (score 13):

Both kinds of enclosed characters are strings.  One type of quote is conveniently used to enclose the other type of quote.  `"'"`  and `'"'`.   The biggest difference between the types of quotes is that enclosed identifier references are substituted for inside double quotes, but not inside single quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Some might say that I'm a little off-topic, but here it is anyway:

You don't necessarily have to choose because of your string's content between:
`echo "It's \"game\" time.";` or `echo 'It\'s "game" time.';`

If you're familiar with the use of the english quotation marks, and the correct character for the apostrophe, you can use either double or single quotes, because it won't matter anymore:
`echo "It’s “game” time.";` and `echo 'It’s “game” time.';`

Of course you can also add variables if needed. Just don't forget that they get evaluated only when in double quotes!